# Create Strongly Typed Dataset for a stored procedure that return more than one table

Tags: c#, database, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a stored procedure that performs 3 select. How do I create a strongly typed dataset that can access all the 3 tables and read the data. Visual studio by default generates a dataset with the 1st table only

I have already tried using visual studio Typed Dataset, to drag and drop the Stored Procedure.

Stored procedure is something like this:

```
Create Procedure GetData
As
Begin
Select ColA, ColB, ColC from TableA
Select ColD, ColE, ColF from TableB
Select ColG, ColH, ColI from TableC
End
```

Comment: The `Dataset` object has a property `Tables` whic is a collection of `DataTables` which should have 3 items in it, (your 3 tables from the selects). Please post your stored procedure as well as expected results and the results you are currently getting.

Comment: It might not be possible; a normal dataadapter will, upon encountering multiple selects, create a table for each but strongly typed dataset tables have names - and one thing that doesnt necessarily come back from a `SELECT * FROM a JOIN B USING c` is a name ; so how would the tableadaoter for the ST dataset know to put this data in the FooBarTable?

Comment: @CaiusJard He could always add a column to each `Select` called `Table Name` and then based off of that column select the correct table from the collection of property `Tables` at least that is how I have done it in the past.

Comment: This Q is specifically about strongly typed datasets designed visually and turned from xml into a set of stub classes using the msdatasetgenerator.exe

Comment: @CaiusJard Then add a node to the xml called Table Name

Comment: Er. I'm not sure that will help with the intrinsic problem of mapping the 3 select queries to 3 named tables, but you seem to have a solution, why not post it?

Comment: @Prashant what's the hardship in creating 3 datatables, 3 tableadapters, each TA does a `SELECT * FROM x` where x is a, b or c, and thus having a 3 table dataset with tableadapters that each only do one query, and load the data in c# by calling each tableadapter.fill ?

Comment: @CaiusJard, i would not want to make multiple DB calls. We would like to avoid multiple DB calls for a single page.

Comment: @Prashant, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're desperate to do this I don't think you'll succeed with a pure strongly-typed designer generated solution; tableadapters are intended to mediate between a local datatable representation of the db data (your strongly typed datatable) and a database query that returns rows. The "table" in tableadapter related to th datatable, not the database table.

A single tableadapter is not intended to function as a mediator between 3 local datatables and a remote procedure that delivers the output of 3 database queries. Primarily it cannot do this because there is nothing the client side code can use to identify, for your sql of...

```
Select ColA, ColB, ColC from TableA
Select ColD, ColE, ColF from TableB
Select ColG, ColH, ColI from TableC
```

...that the results from `select * from TableA` are supposed to go in TableADataTable in your dataset etc. The fact that the data came out of tableA is lost in the transmission over the wire because it is completely irrelevant and might not even be true.

When a tableadapter is correctly used with a single select, it knows implicitly the datatable the results should be put in. TableADataTable has a corresponding TableATableAdapter, and TableATableAdapter selects data from somewhere in the db and stashes it in the TableADataTable - there is no other table in the dataset that TableATableAdapter is designed to manipulate so it doesn't *need* any hints about where the block of data goes after it runs the query. TableATableAdapter can even be loaded with a query that doesn't return any data from the database TableA at all; so long as the query it runs produces a set of columns of th right number and type, that data will go in TableADataTable because that's what TableATableAdapter is hardcoded to do. It serves no other datatable, and has no interest in any other datatable.

Because your stored procedure has no way of indicating to the tableadapter which of the result sets should be stored in which table, the solution you're envisaging cannot work.

The simple rule is: "one dog, one done" - "one db query result set, one tableadapter, one strongly typed datatable"

As such, i firmly recommend you use these things as they were intended:

- Create 3 tableadapters and corresponding datatables for TableA, TableB and TableC
- Fill each independently in your code:

---

```
var ds = new StronglyTypedDataSet();
var ata as new TableATableAdapter();
ata.Fill(ds);
var bta as new TableBTableAdapter();
bta.Fill(ds);
var cta as new TableCTableAdapter();
cta.Fill(ds);
```

---

"We would like to avoid multiple db calls for a single page" doesn't really make sense - it sounds like a solution to a problem you've imagined rather than on that will really happen. There's so little performance advantage to be gained by trying to execute these things in one hit rather than 3. You might disagree, but test it - don't just go off a hunch. Connections are pooled, statements are cached and prepared, 3 statements could be executed concurrently if you really think it will help vastly.

At the end of the day if you have 9 megabytes of data to pull out of a database, the difference in doing it as 3 pulls of 3 mb each versus 1 pull of 9 is going to be miniscule; you aren't waiting 30 seconds for a connection to open, reading 3 mb in a second, waiting another 30s to close it ad having to do it all over again (total time 183 seconds) and having all the bottleneck attributable to the connection management. Even if you *did* have a super latency connection that will take 30s to transmit the SELECT and another 30s to start reading data, you can launch your 3 requests simultaneously and by definition it will take the same time to send the 3 SELECTs as it will to invoke 1 procedure call (both take 61 seconds)

---

If you cannot agree that the reason for trying to do it all in one is spurious then you may wish to keep trying to do it via your chosen method, in which case I think you're going to have to choose:

#### Use a standard dataadapter and dataset

and then move the data into the typed set to work with it

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection String");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storedprocedure", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", whatever); //if you have parameters.
SqlDataAdapter da= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
```

Now you have a dataset with 3 tables in it, it's your problem to figure out which table is which. Let's assume ds.Tables[0] is for TableA:

```
foreach(var ro in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  typedDs.TableA.AddTableARow(ro.ItemArray);
```

Repeat it for b and c tables

#### Convert your 3 queries to 1

Your example seems to indicate all 3 of your tables have the same number of columns. If the columns are the same type too, then you can union the queries, and load them into a single table adapter and fill them into a single strongly typed datatable. You might then have some more work to do splitting them out into separate datatables. Perhaps modify th query to return a column so you can track where the data came from:

```
Select 'tableA' as wherefrom, ColA, ColB, ColC from TableA
UNION ALL
Select 'tableB' as wherefrom, ColD, ColE, ColF from TableB
UNION ALL
Select 'tableC' as wherefrom, ColG, ColH, ColI from TableC
```

It's a mess, a hassle, a hack

---

Why is this so hard? Well.. to quote another old saying: if it's hard, you're doing it wrong. TableAdapters were designed X way and you're trying to use them Y way. Take a step back and examine the reasons behind why you're doing it - that's where the real problem lies

Comment: In that case, Strongly Typed Dataset should be called Strongly Typed Datatable

Comment: It's called a dataset because is a collection of datatables. Datatables are nothing to do with databases or database tables, they're a table (rows and columns) of client side data. They have some similarities to database tables, but only in the sense that strings have some similarities to books. Tableadapters usually fill datatables using database data but they could fill from anywhere. Just because a single tableadapter wont fill multiple datatables from multiple database queries doesn't mean a dataset should be called a datatable

Comment: This is one of the sad things about stackoverflow- you spend a long time and a lot of effort trying to educate, writing an answer more comprehensive than most of the answers out there, and you don't even get so much as a single upvote/thanks