# Fill DataTable from second select in stored procedure (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have a stored procedure in SQL server with 2 select statement. Normally I can fill DataTable from stored procedure with single select statement in vb.net.

[image]

According to attached picture when I am preparing DataSet and adding stored procedure (with several select statement) to it, it is showing only first select columns and I don't know how can get data from second select in this way.

Sample code that I am using for filling a DataTable:

```
Public Class ucTimeSheetReport
  Dim TreeDataTap As New DataSetTimeSheetReportsTableAdapters.spTimeSheetReportDateTreeTableAdapter
  Dim TreeDataDat As New DataSetTimeSheetReports.spTimeSheetReportDateTreeDataTable

  Private Sub UcTimeSheetReport_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      TreeDataTap.Fill(TreeDataDat, 0)
      GridControl1.DataSource = TreeDataDat
  End Sub
End Class
```

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You haven't shown the stored procedure you are trying, but in general, I believe that you will find that the returned dataset is the result of the last `SELECT` in the procedure.

Comment: @daShier It's returning and showing only first select statement.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685614/create-strongly-typed-dataset-for-a-stored-procedure-that-return-more-than-one-t) might be worth a read.

Comment: If a stored procedure has mutiple selects, the dataset will contain the same number of datatables inside the dataset. To access the second table, you can do it like Dataset.Tables(1), and so on. You should pass dataset to the fill method of SqlDataAdapter, like,  SqlDataAdapter.Fill(<Dataset_Variable>), not a DataTable variable